# razor_imu_9dof dies

Tags: ros, imu, razor-imu-9dof

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having problems running the razor_imu_9dof package.

Diamondback on Ubuntu 10.04

```
roslaunch razor_imu_9dof razor.launch
```

Initial problem of not finding `ttyUSB1` was edited to `ttyUSB0` in `razor.launch` and `node.py` files.

I start razor_imu_9dof with my Razor board connected, the two visualization windows come up on the screen, and it may or may not run for a few seconds (watching graphics and `rostopic echo /imuRaw`), and then the process dies.  Graphics stay up, node dies.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/turtlebot/ros_workspace/razor_imu_9dof/razor_imu_9dof/nodes/node.py", line 73, in <module>
    line = ser.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 60, in readline
    c = self.read(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 320, in read
    buf = os.read(self.fd, size-len(read))
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
[node-1] process has died [pid 2964, exit code 1].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/cc609c80-8b2d-11e2-b23a-0016ea6f4f4c/node-1*.log
```

other messages like "out of range" and literal for float() also occur.  the output from the Razor is clean as viewed on the Arduino IDE serial monitor, and will run forever.

Any thoughts?

Alan KM6VV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57965/razor_imu_9dof-dies/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MiniMe](https://answers.ros.org/users/22450/minime/) on 2015-10-13**:
KM6VV- Have you been able to figure this issues out?
I have the same problem and it doesn't appear that you got much help here.
I assume you are using an FTDI serial to USB adapter with your razor card.

Thanks.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-10-14**:
Did you flash the special firmware?

**Comment by [MiniMe](https://answers.ros.org/users/22450/minime/) on 2015-10-19**:
I got it working now.
I did have the special firmware installed and could see the results on arduino serial. I ended up downloading all the razor files again and running the firmware from the new download. Arduino serial no longer shows results but the 3D Visualization Test GUI now works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Isn't this a serial device - looks like you're connecting to USB - try something like ttyAMA0

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2015-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-09-18**:
I think you mean ttyACM0

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-10-14**:
USB-Serial converter (USB-CDC) can be named both, /dev/ttyACM0 or /dev/ttyUSB0, this is hardware/driver specific

/dev/ttyAMA0 sounds very Raspberry Pi specific, but the information about the underlying hardware was not provided.